# Mongoose Not Connecting to MongoDB 4.2

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My current Mongoose connection method is failing to connect. I'm able to connect to my database in the shell without a problem:

```
mongo --username 'admin' --password 'mypassword' --authenticationDatabase 'admin'
```

This is the output it provides:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.2.6
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?authSource=admin&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("d5275c30-cbc6-413f-8dc3-31851219f64b") }
MongoDB server version: 4.2.6
```

However, when I try to use my previously functional Mongoose connection method, it's stalling and not actually connecting. Here's the connection method that I'm using in Mongoose:

```
async () => {

let options = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    keepAlive: true,
    user: process.env.MONGODB_USER,
    pass: process.env.MONGO_PASS,
  };

 try {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, options);
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error("Could not connect to DB.");
    logger.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }

  const db = mongoose.connection;

  db.on("error", (err) => {
    logger.error("Error occured in MongoDB.", err);
  });

  db.on("disconnected", () => {
    logger.error("Connection to MongoDB closed.");
  });

  db.once("open", () => {
    logger.info("Connection to MongoDB opened.");
  });

  return db;

}
```

Eventually, it gives me this error (even though I'm using the same credentials that I'm using from the command line):

```
Error occured in MongoDB.Authentication failed.
(node:29648) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: Authentication failed.
    at new MongooseServerSelectionError (/home/harrison/graphQlServer/source/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/serverSelection.js:24:11)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/home/harrison/graphQlServer/source/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:823:32)
    at Mongoose.connect (/home/harrison/graphQlServer/source/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:333:15)
    at _callee$ (/home/harrison/graphQlServer/source/server/mongodb/connect/index.js:14:14)
    at tryCatch (/home/harrison/graphQlServer/source/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/home/harrison/graphQlServer/source/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:274:22)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (/home/harrison/graphQlServer/source/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/home/harrison/graphQlServer/source/server/mongodb/connect/index.js:14:103)
    at _next (/home/harrison/graphQlServer/source/server/mongodb/connect/index.js:16:194)
    at /home/harrison/graphQlServer/source/server/mongodb/connect/index.js:16:364
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at /home/harrison/graphQlServer/source/server/mongodb/connect/index.js:16:97
    at connect (/home/harrison/graphQlServer/source/server/mongodb/connect/index.js:4:21)
    at _callee$ (/home/harrison/graphQlServer/source/server/index.js:9:9)
    at tryCatch (/home/harrison/graphQlServer/source/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/home/harrison/graphQlServer/source/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:274:22)
(node:29648) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:29648) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:29648) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: Authentication failed.
    at new MongooseServerSelectionError (/home/harrison/graphQlServer/source/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/serverSelection.js:24:11)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/home/harrison/graphQlServer/source/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:823:32)
    at Mongoose.connect (/home/harrison/graphQlServer/source/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:333:15)
    at _callee$ (/home/harrison/graphQlServer/source/server/mongodb/connect/index.js:14:14)
    at tryCatch (/home/harrison/graphQlServer/source/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/home/harrison/graphQlServer/source/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:274:22)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (/home/harrison/graphQlServer/source/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/home/harrison/graphQlServer/source/server/mongodb/connect/index.js:14:103)
    at _next (/home/harrison/graphQlServer/source/server/mongodb/connect/index.js:16:194)
    at /home/harrison/graphQlServer/source/server/mongodb/connect/index.js:16:364
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at /home/harrison/graphQlServer/source/server/mongodb/connect/index.js:16:97
    at connect (/home/harrison/graphQlServer/source/server/mongodb/connect/index.js:4:21)
    at _callee$ (/home/harrison/graphQlServer/source/server/index.js:9:9)
    at tryCatch (/home/harrison/graphQlServer/source/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/home/harrison/graphQlServer/source/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:274:22)
(node:29648) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
```

Here's the MongoDB version that I'm using (installed via the community edition method):

```
db version v4.2.6
git version: 20364840b8f1af16917e4c23c1b5f5efd8b352f8
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distmod: ubuntu1804
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connection string fro mongodb is in this format:

```
mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,...hostN[:portN]][/[defaultauthdb][?options]]
```

So in your case it will be:

```
mongodb://admin:password@127.0.0.1:27017/?authSource=admin
```

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/)